# Ihostbuilder does not contain a definition for configurewebhostdefaults compile error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have created a .NetCore 3.1 FunctionApp. I am trying to implement the code in the startup.cs to access the Azure KeyVault. I need some guidance as I haven't done before. I have so far able to get the following code from the documentation but not sure how to use it. I am also getting compile time error saying that ihostbuilder does not contain a definition for configurewebhostdefaults at line

```
 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error and how to I invoke this method

startup.cs

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace SRL.CustomerOrder
{
    internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ISrlContext, CustomerManagerContext>();
            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

           
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomerManagerContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EnviornmentVariables.SrlContext)));

            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerDetailsRepository, CustomerDetailsRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerOrdersRepository, CustomerOrdersRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IOrderDetailsRepository, OrderDetailsRepository>();

            
            //?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
        }

       

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
                    {
                        var builtConfig = config.Build();

                        AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                                azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                        config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                            $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                            keyVaultClient,
                            new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

**Proposed solution**

Read the connection string from local.settings.json using the enviornment variable. Deploy the application. Azure takes care of retrieving the appropriate secret of that enviornment

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");

            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ISrlContext, CustomerManagerContext>();
            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomerManagerContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerDetailsRepository, CustomerDetailsRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerOrdersRepository, CustomerOrdersRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IOrderDetailsRepository, OrderDetailsRepository>();
        }
```

Comment: `ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder.....` is this code auto generated?

Comment: This is what I see as an example code in most links. So I am not sure

Comment: Are you creating empty Function App in Visual Studio? Can you share the documentation you are following?

Comment: I have created a FunctionApp using Visual studio FunctionApp template. Added a startup file to it. I am seeing no example of accessing the keyvault from this kind of template. The examples that I am seeing are mostly for console kind of applications that have a program.cs startup file which used either IWebHostBuilder or IHostbuilder interface. For e.g https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Not seeing aa example where .Net core 3.1 function app is accessing keyvault pro grammatically in c# code

Comment: Perhaps you don't need startup for azure function app. You can still read values from KeyValue store in function code.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, if you want to read the secret form Azure key vault in Azure function, please refer to the following code

1. [Save the key vault name as a variable in Azure function app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings)
2. [Enable Azure MSI for Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)
3. Configure access policy for the MSI
4. Code

```
 public static class Http
    {
        private static IConfiguration Configuration;

        static Http()
        {
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .AddAzureKeyVault(string.Format("https://{0}.vault.azure.net/", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("keyVaultName")), 
                                   keyVaultClient,
                                   new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager())
                   .Build();

        }

        [FunctionName("Http")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {

           
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var f1= Configuration["DBConnectionString"];
            return new OkObjectResult("the DBConnectionString :" + f1);
        }


        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you so much of giving me a step my step guidance. As with regards reading the secret , I thought it would be as straightforward as writing this one line  var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString"); in your function. I have updated the post. What I have understood is that once the application is deployed it will read the secret for that enviornment which Azure takes care of accordingly. Could you please let me know if my thinking is correct  and also see my updated post.

Comment: @Tom if you use  Key Vault references,  after we deploy, we can read key vault reference as  environment variable : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: Not yet. Shall let you know as soon as I try this out.